# How to remove a line from a JavaScript object (how to use splice)

Tags: javascript

I just want to completely remove the following line "666: {eng: 2, deu: 6}" from an object.

This is my object "words.score":

```
555: {eng: 1, deu: 5}
666: {eng: 2, deu: 6}
777: {eng: 3, deu: 7}
888: {eng: 4, deu: 8}
```

This is the result I'm expecting:

```
555: {eng: 1, deu: 5}
777: {eng: 3, deu: 7}
888: {eng: 4, deu: 8}
```

I tried this:
`Object.keys( words.score ).splice( 666, 1 );`

And also this:
`words.score.splice( 666, 1 );`

And also this:
`Words[score]splice( 666, 1 );`

It does not work. How can I fix it?

Comment: As a side note, **please** read the relevant documentation regarding [`.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). `splice` works on indices - not values.

Comment: yes it works, thank you for the link and for the help ! :)